# HTML File System API - Links to locally stored html or img file

Tags: html5-filesystem

I am assessing File System API for one my projects. I have a requirement to store the zip files I receive as response and use them for offline support. I am successfully able to store the folders after unzipping. Still unable to use them in the web site. I referred to bunch of tutorials and couldn't find an answer. Can someone guide me how to get the link for a particular file stored in the filesystem locally, say html or img file and use them in the website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading local files/directories with html5 filesystem api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243930/reading-local-files-directories-with-html5-filesystem-api)

Answer (score 0):

Your question stems from the most common misunderstanding of the File System API.  The reason the tutorials don't answer your question is because you are not supposed to be locally accessing files stored using the File System API, which stores the data in a "virtualized" manner.  You cannot, therefore, "get the link for a particular file stored in the filesystem locally" as you ask.  If you dig around you *can* find how and where certain browsers store the data, but you will only see unusable obfuscated file name that will not help you in your purpose.

Note that if the API were to operate in the manner you're requesting (allowing direct access to stored data from within the local OS) then it would open a huge security vulnerability for malicious software to be able to directly access potentially sensitive information stored on the local system.  This is one of the reasons the API specifies "virtualized" data storage.

Comment: It is possible to link to a particular resource stored using the FileSystem API from the same path or domain.

var url=filesystem:http://www.example.com/persistent/NewsItems/1/1.html;
$("#somePage").load(url);

It Just works fine. Anyways I moved on from using FileSystem API as this is not going to be a standard as per the message in the W3C page.

Comment: Hi Vignesh. Perhaps I misunderstood.  When you asked for the "file stored in the filesystem locally" I thought you meant directly through the host, such as "C:/whatever/something". Best of luck to you!